# Can you have two nonisomorphic elliptic curves with isomorphic global Tate modules?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $K$ be a number field, and $E_1,E_2/K$ be elliptic curves. Let $G_K$ be the absolute Galois group.

Is it possible for $T_\ell(E_1)$ and $T_\ell(E_2)$ to be isomorphic for all $\ell$ (as $G_K$-modules), even if $E_1\not\cong E_2$?

Comment: This is true if $E_1$/$E_2$ have no rational CM. It can be false (that they need be isomorphic) if they do have CM. If they do have $CM$, then it should be true that there are (roughly?) $|\text{Cl}(\mathcal{O})|$ many non-isomorphic isogenous ECs with this property (where $\mathcal{O}$ is the order we have CM by.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: Uh, not a literature reference. But a little googling turned up this MO post which says the same thing: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/41931/about-isogeny-theorem-for-elliptic-curves